# при попытке что-либо сделать, вызывается ошибка в совершенно другом файле

Tags: python, discord.py

````
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
[Finished in 6.1s]```
````

Comment: мой код:
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('...')
    await bot.logout()

Comment: Вопросы можно редактировать

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая ошибка, но она заключалась в том, что у меня были проблемы с интернет-соединением. В вашем случаем стоит проверить соединение с сетью(если ситуация как у меня), если это не поможет, то возможно у вас выключены `Presence Intents` на портале разработчика.
[https://discord.com/developers/applications/ид_бота/bot](https://discord.com/developers/applications/%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/bot)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]